# Unity3d Instantiate a child prefab from the parent source

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, instantiation

I originally posted this question on answers.unity3d but got no answers
[Unity3d Instantiate a child prefab from the parent source](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/784220/instantiate-a-child-prefab-from-the-parent.html)

I have a Prefab called GreyPiece, When clicked on it, This GreyPiece is supposed to create children of the same type
currently my GreyPiece class has a public Transform object called GreyPieceTransform

```
public Transform greyPieceTransform;
```

This Transform is the same as the main GreyPiece Prefab [dragged and dropped in the Unity3d Editor]
And when clicking on the object, I Instantiate multiple children for this object [as needed] and setting the transform as it's parent

```
Transform greyPiece = Instantiate(greyPieceTransform, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Transform;
greyPiece.parent = transform;
Debug.Log("this id "+transform.GetInstanceID()+"\tprefab id "+greyPieceTransform.GetInstanceID()+"\tchild id "+greyPiece.GetInstanceID());
```

so far so good, if I create one object and click on it , I'd have 1 child

> - parent
>
>   - child

now if I create 2 I'll get this

> - parent
>
>   - child
>   - child
>
>     - child

if I create 3

> - parent
>
>   - child
>   - child
>
>     - child
>   - child
>
>     - child
>     - child
>
>       - child

basically what's happening is that the original GreyPieceTransform seems to be changing, and when I try to instantiate another object it's taking the modified [the current parent] and instantiates from it
this issue doesn't happen if I didn't set the parent of the new instantiated object

**EDIT:** I also added a debug output
The debug.Log output is this

> this id -185148   prefab id -185148   child id -185236
>
> this id -185148   prefab id -185148   child id -185318
>
> this id -185148   prefab id -185148   child id -185418

As you can see , the parent transform and the prefab transform  have the same ids, but they shouldn't

To make this even clearer I decided to name the transforms as "grey "+greyPiece.getInstanceID();
and this is how it looks in the hierarchy view

[image: screenshot]

so now, how can I have the grePieceTransform actually reference the prefab [instantiate from the prefab] instead of it having the same reference as the parent

Comment: I guess that greyPieceTransform points to the prefab instance rather than the prefab itself, doesn't it?

Comment: @Heisenbug apparently what's happening is that the when instantiating an object from a that prefab Transform [greyPieceTransform], it's using it as the current object and modifies the original one [so greyPiece and greyPieceTransform would be the same], I'm not sure how would I prevent this from happening >_<

Comment: I'm not understanding what are you assigning to public field greyPieceTransform. Do you have an instance of a script which field greyPieceTransform points to a prefab (in the project)? I guess no, otherwise it would work as expected. What you probably have is a instance of an object which transform is the same of greyPieceTransform (check the instance id).

Comment: @Heisenbug The public field greyPieceTransform is assigned in the Unity3d Editor [drag and drop] for a prefab,
I'll check their ids and get back to you, Thanks for the idea of the ids !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is the following. At the first instantiation `transform` and `greyPieceTransform` point to the same object. 
You can check it [comparing instance ids](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html).

If this is the case the behavior you see is reasonable. The first time you instantiate a new `GameObject` the source object has no parent and no children so you get just one child. The second time you are instantiating the parent with 1 child and attaching it as a child (fig.2).
And so on.

Here's a simple snippet that may help:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform prefab;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Debug.Log("prefab id " + prefab.GetInstanceID() + " this id " + transform.GetInstanceID());
        }
    }
}
```

It will print different combinations of ids depending on how the object references are set up.

**Case 1**

If `Test` is attached to a object in the `hierarchy` and `prefab` is a reference to a prefab in the project, **ids will be different**.

**Case 2**

If `Test` is attached to a object in the `hierarchy` (which is a prefab instance)and `prefab` is a reference to the linked prefab in the project id will still be different.
(prefab is a link from a instanced object to a prefab. it should be a prefab property override in this case and you should see the bold font in the inspector).**Ids will be different.**

**Case 3**

If `Test` is attached to a prefab and the field prefab points to itself, when it is instantiated the first time(or dragged into the hierarchy), transform and prefab fields will point to the same object (the transform of the prefab instance).
**Ids will be equal.**

> apparently what's happening is that the when instantiating an object
>   from a that prefab Transform [greyPieceTransform], it's using it as
>   the current object and modifies the original one [so greyPiece and
>   greyPieceTransform would be the same]

No. If `greyPieceTransform` and `transform` of the object are different the "original" won't be modified. But probably they aren't.

Comment: you were right,the ids are the same [I edited the question with more info], now I'm not sure how to reference the main prefab when creating a child of it .. any ideas ?

Comment: For a proper advice I need to know the specific use case scenario (but probably it deserve another dedicated question). I guess you can't do what you are trying this way. Probably the simplest solution is split the responsibility. The object instantiated and maintaining the hierarchy chain is stored as prefab. The object who instantiate the other child is another object(eventually stored as another prefab).

Comment: oh well, I'll wait and see if someone else can find that, if not I'll accept your answer and post another question